# Setting up an own instance of Overpass API server

Tags: overpass-api

I need to use overpass-api server local, I found this link: 
[Overpass-Api-Install](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/install)
but it says "Additional functionality like management of areas and the line diagram utils aren't covered yet",what does that mean?Can't I use opverpass-api local and request query?

Comment: Welcome to gis.se. Please edit your thread title to a meaningful question which provides enough details for future readers who might come here with a similar problem looking for solutions.

Comment: I would really recommend to follow this up on the Wiki discussion page: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Talk:Overpass_API/install . There are some tricky parts in the local installation, and the wiki page is much more suited for that kind of discussion.